# Improper use of authoryear-icomp, or bug?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

The biblatex style authoryear-icomp works just fine except for one case which I spotted: when I ask for `\citeyearpar` of two entries with same author and same year. In the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{bib16,
   AUTHOR = {Nomura, Masaaki},
   TITLE = {{The Significance of the Morphographic Principle for the Classification of Writing Systems}},
   JOURNAL = {Written Language and Literacy},
   YEAR = {1988},
   VOLUME = {14},
   PAGES = {58--81},
}

@PHDTHESIS{bib17,
   AUTHOR = {Nomura, Masaaki},
   TITLE = {{The Japanese Mental Lexicon: The Lexical Retrieval and Representation of Two-Kanji Compound Words from a Morphological Perspective}},
   SCHOOL = {University of Tsukuba},
   YEAR = {1988},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear-icomp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\compcitedelim{;\space}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\begin{document}
According to \citet{bib16} and to \citet{bib17}, we have...

According to \citet{bib16,bib17}, we have...

Based on Nomura's \citeyearpar{bib16,bib17} discussion, we have...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

the first two cases are OK, but in the third case the letters ‘a’ and ‘b’ disappear and I get a parenthesis with two identical ‘1988’, which makes no sense. Is this a bug or am I misusing authoryar-icomp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `biblatex` `\cityear` and `\cietyearpar` only print the year or publication and not the complete label consisting of year and year disambiguation letter if required.

The standard styles have starred versions of the standard cite commands `\cite` and `\parencite` that print the citation label without the author/editor names. So you can just say

```
Based on Nomura's \parencite*{bib16,bib17} discussion, we have...
```

Note that you can't use the `natbib`-compatible short form `\citep*` here, because for `natbib` compatibility the starred version prints all names instead. So you will have to  use the `biblatex` name `\parencite*`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\compcitedelim{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{bib16,
  AUTHOR  = {Nomura, Masaaki},
  TITLE   = {The Significance of the Morphographic Principle
             for the Classification of Writing Systems},
  JOURNAL = {Written Language and Literacy},
  YEAR    = {1988},
  VOLUME  = {14},
  PAGES   = {58--81},
}
@PHDTHESIS{bib17,
  AUTHOR = {Nomura, Masaaki},
  TITLE  = {The {Japanese} Mental Lexicon:
            The Lexical Retrieval and Representation of
            Two-Kanji Compound Words from a Morphological Perspective},
  SCHOOL = {University of Tsukuba},
  YEAR   = {1988},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
According to \citet{bib16} and to \citet{bib17}, we have...

According to \citet{bib16,bib17}, we have...

Based on Nomura's \parencite*{bib16,bib17} discussion, we have...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Based on Nomura’s (1988a,b) discussion, we have...]